# get posts with a mentioned user in Instagram

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, instagram

i want to get the posts with a mentioned user (@username), how can i do this?
I already searched here:
http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/
https://github.com/Instagram/instagram-ruby-gem

Something like this but with a username, not a tag.

```
 get "/tags" do
  client = Instagram.client(:access_token => session[:access_token])
  html = "<h1>Search for tags, get tag info and get media by tag</h1>"
  tags = client.tag_search('cat')
  html << "<h2>Tag Name = #{tags[0].name}. Media Count =  #{tags[0].media_count}. </h2><br/><br/>"
  for media_item in client.tag_recent_media(tags[0].name)
    html << "<img src='#{media_item.images.thumbnail.url}'>"
  end
  html
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with the current Instagram API.

In my case I am doing this:

If you know which users might have mentioned your desired user, you may query their recent/full media and extract medias mentioning your user.
This way I also find photos with the desired user mentioned in the description.